# sed command for inserting text inside single quote

Tags: bash, unix, sed, single-quotes

Suppose there's a text file with the following line:

```
export MYSQL_ADMIN=''
```

I want to insert text inside that single quote using the `sed` command, so that it changes to something like this for example:

```
export MYSQL_ADMIN='abc1'
```

What is the appropriate `sed` command for that in Linux?
I tried

```
sed -i -e ''/MYSQL_ADMIN/s/''/'abc1'/g"
```

but it didn't work.

Comment: Does your file contain only this line?

Comment: Please add to your question (no comment): What have you searched for, and what did you find? What have you tried, and how did it fail?

Comment: no it contains one more line

Comment: Please show the complete file. Check your command. Did you really use two single quotes at the beginning and a double quote at the end? What exactly means "didnt work". Please [edit] your question and show the error message or wrong result. I suggest to try `sed` commands without `-i` first because you may be overwriting your input with wrong output.

Answer (score 1):

Something like `sed -i "s;export MYSQL_ADMIN=.*;export MYSQL_ADMIN='abc1';" /path/to/file.ext`

`-i` modify file in place
`s` means substitute,

First block is what you are matching as an regular expression - the `.*` matches everything to the end of the line, this ensures you don't keep any text on that line after the substitue - and second block is what you are replacing with that match.

Always check the file after each run of sed if there is no error and check what changed.

To get the single quotes to print you may have to do `""'""` like `""'""abc1""'""`

Answer (score 0):

It is important to understand that although

> I want to insert text inside that single quote using the `sed` command

is a perfectly good characterization of the effect you want to achieve, it does not map directly onto operations from `sed`'s repertoire.  With `sed`, the appropriate tool for most line modifications is the `s` command, which ***s***ubstitutes specified text for one or more matches to a specified regular expression.  That would be the most natural thing to use for your case.

Additionally, it is important with `sed` to understand how and when to bind commands to specific lines.  If you don't do that for a given command then it is applied to *all* lines.  Sometimes that's fine, but other times it will produce unwanted results.

> I tried
>
> ```
> sed -i -e ''/MYSQL_ADMIN/s/''/'abc1'/g"
> ```
>
> but it didn't work.

The two leading single quotes in that `sed` expression match each other, leaving the trailing double quote unmatched.  Also, you do not specify the name of the file to modify.  This variation would at least be valid shell syntax, and it would have the desired effect on the specified line appearing in file `my_script`:

```
sed -i -e "/MYSQL_ADMIN/s/''/'abc1'/g" my_script
```

That might also make other, unwanted changes, however.

You need to make some assumptions about the content of the file in order to do such a thing at all.  The above depends on the text `MYSQL_ADMIN` and `''` to appear on the same line only in the line(s) you want to modify.  That may turn out to hold, but it seems unnecessarily risky.  An assumption more likely to hold in general would be that there will be only one assignment to variable `MYSQL_ADMIN`, or that it is acceptable to modify all such assignments that assign a single-quote-delimited empty value.

Going with the latter, one might end up with this:

```
sed -i -e "s/\<MYSQL_ADMIN=''\(\s\|$\)/MYSQL_ADMIN='abc1'\1/g" my_script
```

The pattern `\<MYSQL_ADMIN=''\(\s\|$\)` improves on your plain `MYSQL_ADMIN`  in these significant ways:

- the `\<` causes it to match only immediately after a word boundary -- start of line, whitesepace, or punctuation.  This prevents substitutions for other variables whose names happen to end with `MYSQL_ADMIN`.  If you prefer, it would be even stronger to instead anchor the match to the beginning of the line with `^`.
- including the `=''` in the pattern distinguishes between `MYSQL_ADMIN` and variables whose names contain that as an initial substring.  It also ensures that the `''` that gets replaced, if any, goes with the variable and does not merely appear somewhere else on the line.
- the `\(\s\|$\)` both matches and captures either a whitespace character or the empty string at the end of a line.  This distinguishes between assignments of an empty value and assignments of values that are merely prefixed by `''` (which is valid if the file is a shell script).  Having included it in the match, the capture allows the matched text, if any, to be preserved in the output (via the `\1` in the replacement).

Because that matches the whole assignment, a complete assignment must appear in the replacement, too.  On the other hand, this means that (probably)  you can apply the command to every line, as shown, with no particular loss of efficiency relative to the previous command.

Even that might produce changes you didn't want, however, such as in comment lines or quoted text.